# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createFisherFaceRecognizer'

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu-16.04, face-recognition

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) python2.7 Open-CV 3.1.0
I've followed the steps for downloading Repository for Open-CV extra modules to activate this function via 
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib, 
However i got the same error, i also tried using the latest Open-CV 3.2.0 instead of 3.1.0 but i have got the same error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createFisherFaceRecognizer'.
```

The part of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import os
class TrainFisherFaces:
    def __init__(self):
        cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
        self.face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
        self.face_dir = 'data'
        self.face_name = sys.argv[1]
        self.path = os.path.join(self.face_dir, self.face_name)
        if not os.path.isdir(self.path):
            os.mkdir(self.path)
        self.model = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that **createFisherFaceRecognizer()** is in the sub-module **cv2.face** in python. To access it you should **cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer()**.

**Source**:

Adapted from the tutorial [example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d60/tutorial_face_main.html) for face recognition in c++. I have the the installation as the one described in the question and tested it out.

Comment: It gives me this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'

Comment: That's weird. I got exactly the same configuration that you have with OpenCV 3.1. Works perfectly for me if I call createFisherFaceRecognizer() from cv2.face module.

Comment: Thanks, i have found that i didn't uninstall my old OpenCV correctly, after downloading it again correctly following the instructions and adding cv2.face, it probably worked!

Answer (score 3):

I followed the instructions here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-contrib-python

And simply has to do: pip install opencv-contrib-python

Also, I had to use cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create()

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by this way:

```
self.model = cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create()
```